# My app restart to first activity when I press a button

Tags: android, restart

I'm developing an registration part of my app and I'm having a problem once I started to pass the array dados[] to another activity, since then, when I click do proceed, the app verify the informations and change to next activity, but right now it just come back to the main activity, how can I solve this?

**CODE cadastroPt1**

```
package com.example.techtable;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Currency;


public class CadastroPt1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btnPt2;

    // Objetos para o autocomplete do genero
    String[] generos = {"Masculino", "Feminino", "Outro"};
    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTxt;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterItens;

    // Declaração dos inputs
    EditText txtNome;
    EditText txtEmail;
    EditText txtSenhaCadastro;
    EditText txtConfirmeSenha;
    EditText editTextPhone;

    // Array dos dados
    String[] dados = new String[6];
    String genero;


    public static final String EXTRA_TEXT = "com.example.application.techtable.EXTRA_TEXT";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro_pt1);

        // Instanciamento dos editTexts
        txtNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
        txtEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEmailCadastro);
        txtSenhaCadastro = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtSenhaCadastro);
        txtConfirmeSenha = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtConfirmeSenha);
        editTextPhone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);


    }

    // Evento ao clicar no botao
    public void ClickBotao(View i){
        // Coleta de dados inseridos:
        dados[0] = txtNome.getText().toString();
        dados[1] = txtEmail.getText().toString();
        dados[2] = txtSenhaCadastro.getText().toString();
        dados[3] = txtConfirmeSenha.getText().toString();
        dados[4] = genero;
        dados[5] = editTextPhone.getText().toString();


        if(verificarInformacoes(txtNome, txtEmail, txtSenhaCadastro, txtConfirmeSenha, editTextPhone)) {
            irParaPt2();
        }
    }

    public void irParaPt2(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(CadastroPt1.this, CadastroPt2.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT, dados);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    public boolean verificarInformacoes(EditText txtNome, EditText txtEmail,EditText txtSenhaCadastro, EditText txtConfirmeSenha, EditText editTextPhone) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro_pt1);

        if(verificarNome(txtNome)
                && verificarEmail(txtEmail)
                && verificarSenha(txtConfirmeSenha, txtSenhaCadastro)
                && verificarTel(editTextPhone))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    private boolean verificarNome(EditText txtNome){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro_pt1);
        String val = txtNome.getText().toString();

        if(val.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Preencha nome!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        } else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean verificarEmail(EditText txtEmail){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro_pt1);
        String val = txtEmail.getText().toString();

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Preencha email!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        } else if (!val.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Email invalido!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean verificarSenha(EditText txtConfirmeSenha, EditText txtSenhaCadastro){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro_pt1);
        String val1 = txtConfirmeSenha.getText().toString();
        String val2 = txtSenhaCadastro.getText().toString();
        String passwordVal = "^" +
                "(?=.*[0-9])" +       //at least 1 digit
                "(?=.*[a-z])" +       //at least 1 lower case letter
                "(?=.*[A-Z])" +       //at least 1 upper case letter
                "(?=.*[a-zA-Z])" +      //any letter
                "(?=.*[@#$%^&+=?])" +   //at least 1 special character
                "(?=\\S+$)" +           //no white spaces
                ".{4,}" +               //at least 4 characters
                "$";

        if (val1.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Preencha senha!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        } else if (!val1.matches(passwordVal)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Senha muito fraca", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean verificarTel(EditText editTextPhone){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro_pt1);
        String val = editTextPhone.getText().toString();
        if(val.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Preencha telefone!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        } else if(val.length() != 11){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Telefone inválido!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        } else{
            return true;

        }
    }




}
```

**cadastroPt1 xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CadastroPt1">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCadastrar"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/laranja"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:onClick="ClickBotao"
        android:text="Cadastre-se"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:cornerRadius="35px"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.476"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout3" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4">

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="-6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView17">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:buttonTint="@color/laranja"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                android:text="Feminino"
                android:textColorHighlight="@color/laranja"
                android:textColorLink="@color/laranja"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:buttonTint="@color/laranja"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:text="Masculino"
                android:textColorHighlight="@color/laranja"
                android:textColorLink="@color/laranja"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:buttonTint="@color/laranja"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                android:text="Outro"
                android:textColorHighlight="@color/laranja"
                android:textColorLink="@color/laranja"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
            android:text="Gênero:"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextPhone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
            android:text="Nome completo:"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtNome"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
            android:text="Senha:"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtSenhaCadastro"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtEmailCadastro" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtNome"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

            android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Nome"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="14sp"
            android:padding="8sp"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView9"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtConfirmeSenha"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Confirme sua senha"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="14sp"
            android:padding="8sp"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
            android:text="Confirme sua senha:"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtConfirmeSenha"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtSenhaCadastro" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
            android:text="E-mail:"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtEmailCadastro"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtNome" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtEmailCadastro"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

            android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="E-mail"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="14sp"
            android:padding="8sp"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView11"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtSenhaCadastro"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

            android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Senha"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="14sp"
            android:padding="8sp"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView10"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
            android:text="Telefone"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtConfirmeSenha" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextPhone"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Telefone"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="14sp"
            android:padding="8sp"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView20" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="230sp"
        android:layout_height="80sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logotechtablecolorida" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/lgeorge_bold"
        android:text="Cadastre-se"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**LOGCAT**

```
2022-07-10 19:19:36.361 11175-11175/com.example.techtable D/DecorView: setCaptionType = 0, this = DecorView@dfc13d1[]
2022-07-10 19:19:36.419 11175-11175/com.example.techtable W/ample.techtabl: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-07-10 19:19:36.421 11175-11175/com.example.techtable W/ample.techtabl: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-07-10 19:19:36.817 11175-11175/com.example.techtable D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: 'e58891c', fd=76
2022-07-10 19:19:36.823 11175-11175/com.example.techtable I/ViewRootImpl@6549dcc[MainActivity]: setView = com.android.internal.policy.DecorView@dfc13d1 TM=true
2022-07-10 19:19:36.914 11175-11175/com.example.techtable I/SurfaceControl: assignNativeObject: nativeObject = 0 Surface(name=null)/@0x4a657a9 / android.view.SurfaceControl.readFromParcel:1117 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout:1836 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:9005 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3360 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2618 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:9971 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1010 android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks:809 android.view.Choreographer.doFrame:744 android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run:995 
2022-07-10 19:19:36.917 11175-11175/com.example.techtable I/ViewRootImpl@6549dcc[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=(0,0,720,1560) new=(0,0,720,1560) req=(720,1560)0 dur=21 res=0x7 s={true 531037659136} ch=true fn=-1
2022-07-10 19:19:36.938 11175-11175/com.example.techtable I/ViewRootImpl@6549dcc[MainActivity]: [DP] dp(1) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.reportNextDraw:10957 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3845 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2618 
2022-07-10 19:19:36.940 11175-11175/com.example.techtable I/ViewRootImpl@6549dcc[MainActivity]: [DP] pd() Asnyc report
2022-07-10 19:19:36.965 11175-11938/com.example.techtable I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
2022-07-10 19:19:36.966 11175-11938/com.example.techtable W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2022-07-10 19:19:36.969 11175-11938/com.example.techtable I/gralloc: Arm Module v1.0
2022-07-10 19:19:37.003 11175-11175/com.example.techtable I/ViewRootImpl@6549dcc[MainActivity]: [DP] pdf(0) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.lambda$performDraw$1$ViewRootImpl:4668 android.view.-$$Lambda$ViewRootImpl$DJd0VUYJgsebcnSohO6h8zc_ONI.run:6 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:938 
2022-07-10 19:19:37.004 11175-11175/com.example.techtable I/ViewRootImpl@6549dcc[MainActivity]: [DP] rdf()
2022-07-10 19:19:37.020 11175-11175/com.example.techtable I/ViewRootImpl@6549dcc[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
2022-07-10 19:19:37.021 11175-11175/com.example.techtable D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@dfc13d1[MainActivity]
2022-07-10 19:19:37.021 11175-11175/com.example.techtable D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2022-07-10 19:19:37.029 11175-11175/com.example.techtable D/EmergencyMode: [EmergencyManager] android createPackageContext successful: com.example.techtable
2022-07-10 19:19:37.039 11175-11175/com.example.techtable D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@dfc13d1[MainActivity]
2022-07-10 19:19:37.039 11175-11175/com.example.techtable D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2022-07-10 19:19:37.040 11175-11175/com.example.techtable D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2022-07-10 19:19:37.040 11175-11175/com.example.techtable I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2022-07-10 19:19:37.048 11175-11934/com.example.techtable D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: 'ClientS', fd=83
2022-07-10 19:19:37.050 11175-11175/com.example.techtable D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@dfc13d1[MainActivity]
2022-07-10 19:19:37.050 11175-11175/com.example.techtable D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2022-07-10 19:19:37.050 11175-11175/com.example.techtable D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2022-07-10 19:19:37.059 11175-11175/com.example.techtable I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject s[535159703584]
2022-07-10 19:19:37.059 11175-11175/com.example.techtable I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject e[535159703584]
2022-07-10 19:19:37.059 11175-11175/com.example.techtable I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject s[535159703872]
2022-07-10 19:19:37.059 11175-11175/com.example.techtable I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject e[535159703872]
2022-07-10 19:19:37.548 11175-11931/com.example.techtable W/System: A resource failed to call close.
```

Comment: Can you post, `CadastroPt2` there is a chance it is crashing, which will cause the caller to crash  `CadastroPt1`. Thus leaving the only remaining activity the `MainActivity`.

Comment: Sure! just a moment.

Comment: I've just analysed again the code and it was a problem in CadastroPt2 indeeed, because I was trying to pass a vector between activities and something gone wrong